# jq - Multiple Object Identifier-Indexes with Argument

Tags: json, bash, jq

I have an environment variable that contains the path `.foo.bar`. I'm trying to access the data at `.foo.bar` with that environment variable. So, let's say I had the following JSON:

```
{
  "foo": {
    "bar": 10
  }
}
```

I could access this with jq as such ([jq playground link](https://jqplay.org/s/FeNC62yVYb)):

```
jq '.foo.bar'
```

Now if I want to access this with the environment variable instead, I'd do something like this:

```
$ JSON_INDEX=".foo.bar"
$ cat /tmp/data.json | jq --arg KEY $JSON_INDEX '.[$KEY]'
```

However, this outputs null, because as far as I understand, you can't use paths in `[]`? I'm trying to avoid from having to reformat the `JSON_INDEX` variable if possible. Is there any way I can do this in native `jq` without altering the variable?

Comment: `.[$KEY]` is looking for `{ ".foo.bar": 10 }`; it has a distinct, and also-valid, meaning.

Comment: (aside: using all-caps names for your own variables in shell is bad form -- those are defined by the POSIX specification as being in the namespace used for variables that modify behavior of the shell itself or other POSIX-specified tools, whereas names with at least one lowercase character are reserved for application usage; see https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html, fourth paragraph).

Comment: In the answer to the linked duplicate, see the reference to `getpath`, which can also be found in https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/